# Picture value of TImage is not staying TBitmap

Tags: delphi, devexpress, timage, tbitmap

In a Delphi XE3 project, I am having an issue in changing a bitmap image.  In the design view the **picture** value of a **TImage** is **TBitmap**, as shown:

[image: TBitmap]

However, when I change the image, the **picture** value is a **TDXSmartImage**:

[image: TDXSmartImage]

So far, the actual image type has had no influence on keeping the **picture** value a TBitmap.  Bitmaps, PNGs, JPEGs, have all been tried, as well as other formats. Additionally, when the project is built and run using the **TDXSmartImage**, there is no actual image.  There is only a white block with all of the other visual components properly displayed on the screen.

I have not been able to track down how to keep the **TBitmap** format and prevent the **TDXSmartImage** format from being "used".

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: What software did you install that resulted in this behaviour? Doesn't happen in a stock installation. So here is your task? Find out which third party library, that you installed, is responsible. Let us know when you have the answer.

Comment: TDx is usually associated with Developer Express controls. If you have them installed, they're what's causing this behavior.  Contact DevEx to ask support questions about their components via their forums.

Comment: See [How to prevent devexpress from assigning tdxsmartimage](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T393193) on the DexExpress support forum.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by uninstalling the Dev Express packages.  This project was inherited from another developer, who had a fascination with third party components.

While this may seem like a cop-out, these components are not used anywhere in the project.

As a side note, simply disabling the packages was the first step taken that provided a resolution.  However (much to my surprise), the Delphi XE3 development suite re-enabled the packages the next time it was booted up.